# Debo cambiar la variable display en css para que funcione menú móvil en php

Tags: php, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El menú móvil de mi sitio web www.camila109.cl no funciona, adjunto código php y css.

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    line-height: normal;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background-image: none;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según el problema que he visto, es que al visitar tu web en un movil, no se abre el popup de menu. Si quieres que al pasar el mouse por el logo se abra el menu,tienes que insertar este css:

```
#mobile-navigation-menu {
    margin-top:22px;
    margin-right:5px;
    float:right;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
/*Le estas diciendo que al pasar el mouse por el logo (modo :hover), la clase #mobile-navigation-menu-list se ponga en display:block*/
#top-navigation-menu-wrap:hover #mobile-navigation-menu-list{ 
    display:block;
}
#mobile-navigation-menu-list {
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    z-index:1000;
    right:-0px;
    width:300px;
    background:#fff;
    padding:20px;
    height:260px;
    overflow:auto;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #999;
}
```

Comment: claro el problema es que no se abre el popup del menú móvil. Gracias